# If cudaMalloc() allocates global memory, then why do I need cudaMemcpy()?

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

I am learning cuda, and so far I have learned that cuda has `cudaMalloc()` function which allocates memory for a global object. But now in some matrix multiplication code, I have seen that they are using another function called `cudaMemcpy()` which copies an object from host to device or the other way around. But I do not understand why it is needed? Since `cudaMalloc()` is allocating global memmory, all the device cores should have access to it, shouldn't they?

Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: Next time, please consider proofing your question before submitting. By doing this, careless typos can be fixed and can improve readability greatly.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at slides 10, 11, and 12 in [this deck](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/GTC_Express_Sarah_Tariq_June2011.pdf).  They illustrate the basic processing flow.  The cudaMemcpy that usually appears before the kernel call corresponds to the activity in slide 10.  The kernel call itself is represented by slide 11.  Slide 12 represents the cudaMemcpy that occurs after the kernel call.  GPU `cudaMalloc` is similar to CPU `malloc` -- it only allocates space, but does not populate it with any data.  Once you have allocated the space on the GPU using `cudaMalloc`, it's necessary to copy the data to it using `cudaMemcpy`.    In this case, "global memory" refers to the memory *on the device*, i.e. on the right hand side of the slides 10, 11, and 12.  The device kernel can only work with data that is on the device, i.e. that has been moved to the DRAM on the right hand side of slides 10, 11, and 12.

Answer (score 5):

cudaMalloc() only gives you a chunk of memory on GPU memory with undefined initial value. You have to copy your intended memory content from host or somewhere on device.

Answer (score 1):

malloc() allocates dynamic memory on host i.e. on cpu.
Allocating global memory on device you need to call cudaMalloc().
To operate on data using gpu your hole data needs to transfer on global memory.
cudaMalloc() only allocates memory, it'll not copies your data on device memory. So, to copy your data from host memory to device memory you need to call cudaMemcpy().

Answer (score 0):

The code that runs on the CPU can only access buffers allocated in its (host) memory while the GPU code (CUDA kernels) can only access memory in device (GPU) memory. Since the code that initializes the input matricies in the matrix multiplication example runs on the CPU, it can only do so in host memory. It must then call cudaMemcpy in order to copy those matricies to the space it allocated in device memory, since it cannot write it there directly. The CUDA kernel is then launched which performs its processing on the matricies in device memory and stores the results in another buffer in device memory. cudaMemcpy is then used again once the kernel finishes to copy the results out of device memory into host memory so the results can be used by the host code again (to diplay or store the results, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

**All the memory allocations and copying can be done from the host only.**

For all the GPU activities the memory is to be allocated in the device (GPU), which should be initiated from the host(CPU).

After that a memory from host is to be transferred to device (Memcpy) for the computation/processing.

Then after this, the kernel is to be called for computation.

Then the result computed in the device is transferred back to host through Memcpy.

Comment: That isn't strictly true. Memory allocation inside kernels has been supported for several years, as has zero copy memory, which allows the gpu to write into host memory without an explicit memcpy call on the host.

Comment: But still you need a device type pointer by calling cudaHostGetDevicePointer() in a UnifiedVirtual Addres Space. We cannot directly use the host memory in the GPU, ie, memory allcoated using malloc or new in host.